# Extend the drupal contact form

Tags: emails

How do I add fields to the standard Drupal contact form? Can this be done programmatically or is it a task for a module?

Comment: Maybe you should give webforms a go...

Comment: pls see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that programmatically using the function [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module. Follow [this for creating a custom module](http://drupal.org/node/1074362).

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'contact_personal_form') {
    $form['new_field'] = array (
      '#title' => t('New field'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      'description' => t('The description of the new field goes here...'),
      '#required' => TRUE, // make the user to fill it compulsorily           
    );
  }
}
```

**Update:** I forgot to mention that, the above code will just add the field to the form. The field is not added the mail you send. You should implement [`hook_mail_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7) and add the field to the body, by something like:

```
function MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if($message['id'] == 'contact_user_mail') {
    $message['body'][] = $message['params']['new_field'];  //value of key 'new_field' same as in $form['new_field'] above in form alter
  }
}
```

Comment: And the site wide contact form would be contact_site_form I guess.

Comment: @Neograph734 - you can find out the `$form_id` of any form by printing it out in the `hook_form_alter`, in this case just add `echo $form_id;` before the `if` condition above. Note that the `$form_id` will be printed on the respective form.