# How can i change registration email send to admin

Tags: emails, users

I was wondering how to change the standard text in the email send to the administrator when a new user has registered.

Is there a way to change the text? Maybe the same way as you can change the emails send to the user when registered?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

Unlike normal users there's is no UI to change the text of the message sent to administrator on account creation.

You could implement [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7), to achieve this via a custom module:

```
function MODULE_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'user_register_pending_approval_admin') {
    //$message['body'] is the array you want to change.
    $message['body'][] = 'Your custom message for admin goes here.....';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this one. Do you also know how to put some shorthand code for the fields that are used? I created extra fields like: name, address etc..

Comment: @Ziggy You can do that from the values from `$message['params']` array. I've posted a [similar solution](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/50908/6461) some time ago. You can check it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Mail Edit](http://drupal.org/project/mail_edit) module allows you to alter mail templates including the one you mention, which appears on its list with the key "register_pending_approval_admin".

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use the [rules module](http://drupal.org/project/rules)

You create an action (send an email) on a user creation event

Comment: OP wants to change the text of the mail which is sent by default by the user module on account creation; and don't want to send another mail.